# Create a task in mybb to automatically recount and rebuild forums and threads every 1 minute

Tags: php, task, scheduled-tasks, mybb

I need to create a task that performs the same function as the recount_rebuild.php file in MyBB to automatically recount the forums and threads every 1 minute. This is the code I use as a task in MyBB, but the execution does not seem to have worked, the values ​​presented on the home page are the same:

```
    <?php

require_once 'global.php';

require_once MYBB_ROOT.'inc/functions_rebuild.php';
require_once MYBB_ROOT.'inc/functions.php';

function task_recount_rebuild_forum_counters($task)
{
    global $db, $mybb, $lang;

    $query = $db->simple_select("forums", "fid", '', array('order_by' => 'fid', 'order_dir' => 'asc'));
    while($forum = $db->fetch_array($query))
    {
        $update['parentlist'] = make_parent_list($forum['fid']);
        $db->update_query("forums", $update, "fid='{$forum['fid']}'");
        rebuild_forum_counters($forum['fid']);
    }
}

function task_recount_rebuild_thread_counters($task)
{
    global $db, $mybb, $lang;

    $query = $db->simple_select("threads", "tid", '', array('order_by' => 'tid', 'order_dir' => 'asc'));
    while($thread = $db->fetch_array($query))
    {
        rebuild_thread_counters($thread['tid']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. And your question / problem is....? See also [ask]. Remember that this isn't a free write-my-code or do-my-thinking service. Have you researched or tried anything? Where are you stuck exactly? What do you want us to tell you, specifically?

Comment: I tried to create a php file inside the tasks folder that replicated the acp_rebuild_forum_counters() and
acp_rebuild_thread_counters(), I added my file to MyBB's task manager but it didn't work.

Comment: didn't work how? What went wrong when you ran it? Be specific. Provide a [mre] of the issue / error / problem, so we can help to fix it. If you don't know what went wrong, do some debugging and then come back to us. P.S. You can [edit] your question to add code and new details. We can't fix unspecified problems with invisible code.

Comment: I put the code I used so you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with the following code

```
    <?php

function task_rebuildforumcounters($task)
{
    try
    {
        global $db, $mybb, $lang;

        require_once MYBB_ROOT."/inc/functions.php";
        require_once MYBB_ROOT."/inc/functions_rebuild.php";
        require_once MYBB_ROOT.$mybb->config['admin_dir']."/inc/functions.php";

        $query = $db->simple_select("forums", "fid", '', array('order_by' => 'fid', 'order_dir' => 'asc'));
        while($forum = $db->fetch_array($query))
        {
            $update['parentlist'] = make_parent_list($forum['fid']);
            $db->update_query("forums", $update, "fid='{$forum['fid']}'");
            rebuild_forum_counters($forum['fid']);
        }

        add_task_log($task, "Recontagem de foruns realizada com sucesso");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        add_task_log($task, "Erro ao realizar recontagem de foruns");
    }
}
```